# Comparar un rango de fechas con BETWEEN en mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy creando un módulo en un sistema con PHP y MySQL, en donde estoy realizando una agenda para eventos. Tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos:

- `id_evento`
- `nombre_evento`
- `fechaInicial`
- `fechaFinal`
- `id_ubicacion`

En el formulario de creación para la agenda, el usuario tiene dos `input` de tipo `date`, donde ingresa la fecha inicial y la fecha final de su evento, supongamos que tengo dado de alta un evento con la `fechaIncial = '2016-02-18'` y `fechaFinal = '2016-02-22'`.

Si el usuario ingresa `fechaIncial = '2016-02-19'` y `fechaFinal = '2016-02-19'` como válido que se encuentra ya registrado un evento entre el 18 y el 22, que es donde entraría el dia 19.

Actualmente tengo esta consulta pero no estoy seguro de su funcionamiento porque solo me valida los `OR`

```sql
SELECT id_evento,nombre_evento,id_ex_ubicacion,fecha_ini_evt,fecha_fin_evt,hora_ini_evt‌​,hora_fin_evt
FROM eventos
WHERE fecha_ini_evt >= '2016-02-19'
    AND fecha_fin_evt <= '2016-02-19'
        OR fecha_fin_evt BETWEEN '2016-02-19' AND '2016-02-19'
        OR fecha_ini_evt BETWEEN '2016-02-19' AND '2016-02-19'
    AND id_ex_ubicacion = 1
```

Comment: Hola jvieyra, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Por favor indica qué has intentado para resolver el problema. ¿Has intentado hacer algún query con los datos que tienes en la mano? ¿Cómo luce tu query ahora? ¿O tienes problema incluso con cómo formar ese query? Agregar estos detalles es importante en las preguntas.

Comment: Que tal , perdon, solo plasme la idea general tengo esta consulta pero no estoy seguro de su funcionamiento porque solo me valida los OR

SELECT id_evento,nombre_evento,id_ex_ubicacion,fecha_ini_evt,fecha_fin_evt,hora_ini_evt,hora_fin_evt
FROM eventos
WHERE fecha_ini_evt >= '2016-02-19' AND fecha_fin_evt <= '2016-02-19' 
OR fecha_fin_evt BETWEEN '2016-02-19' AND  '2016-02-19'
OR fecha_ini_evt BETWEEN '2016-02-19' AND '2016-02-19' 
AND id_ex_ubicacion = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer tu problema es de uso de paréntesis. Cuando utilices una sentencia `OR` siempre debes tener presente usarlos, sino tu query traerá todos los datos posibles para las validaciones antes y después del `OR`.

Tu query debería lucir así:

```sql
SELECT id_evento,nombre_evento,id_ex_ubicacion,fecha_ini_evt,fecha_fin_evt,hora_ini_evt‌​,hora_fin_evt
FROM eventos
WHERE ((fecha_ini_evt <= '2016-02-19'
    AND fecha_fin_evt >= '2016-02-19')
        OR fecha_fin_evt BETWEEN '2016-02-19' AND '2016-02-19'
        OR fecha_ini_evt BETWEEN '2016-02-19' AND '2016-02-19')
    AND id_ex_ubicacion = 1
```

Comment: Arreglado. Por favor revisa nuevamente.

Answer (score -1):

este me valida si el rango inicial y final de una hora , si hay una respuesta esta me sacar un resultado

```
  SELECT * FROM `horario` WHERE inicio <= '17:00' and final >= '22:00' AND 
  clinica_IDclinica='2' OR inicio BETWEEN '17:00' AND '22:00' AND 
  clinica_IDclinica='2' OR final  BETWEEN '17:00' AND '22:00' AND 
  clinica_IDclinica='2'
```