# Crear tabla para facturar por rango de fechas escogidas

Tags: mysql, relaciones, modelorelacional

Lo que quiero hacer es facturar un servicio por un rango de fechas, me explico, tengo las siguientes tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, es una relación de uno a muchos, si quisiera facturar el servicio, le agregaría un campo *factura* a la tabla *servicios*. Pero si quisiera facturar un *rango de fechas*, no se como podría hacerlo. Por ejemplo, tengo los siguientes datos:

- Tabla *servicio_fecha*

```
[
  {
    "id_servicio_fecha":"1",
    "servicio_id":"1",
    "fecha":"2020-12-01 18:16:54"
  },
  {
    "id_servicio_fecha":"2",
    "servicio_id":"1",
    "fecha":"2020-12-02 18:16:54"
  },
  {
    "id_servicio_fecha":"3",
    "servicio_id":"1",
    "fecha":"2020-12-03 18:16:54"
  },
  {
    "id_servicio_fecha":"4",
    "servicio_id":"1",
    "fecha":"2020-12-04 18:16:54"
  }
]
```

- Tabla *servicios*

```
[
  {
    "id_servicio":"1",
    "nombre":"Servicio 01"
  },
  {
    "id_servicio":"2",
    "nombre":"Servicio 02"
  },
  {
    "id_servicio":"3",
    "nombre":"Servicio 03"
  },
  {
    "id_servicio":"4",
    "nombre":"Servicio 04"
  }
]
```

Lo que quiero es facturar digamos el rango de `id_servicio_fecha:1` y `id_servicio_fecha:2`. También quiero facturar el rango de `id_servicio_fecha:3` y `id_servicio_fecha:4`.

¿Qué tabla podría agregar para hacer eso posible? Intenté crear esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, se relaciona con la tabla *servicio_fecha* y se toma el mismo *id*, haciendo esto obtendría lo que quiero, pero veo que es ineficiente por tomarse el mismo *id* como campo.

> **PD:** Por si no me entendieron: **Quiero crear una tabla x donde pueda facturar por un rango de fechas, esto para guardar los datos**

¡Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

primero que nada indicas que quieres facturar servicios ok; eso se puede y me dices que el filtro lo quieres hacer por un rango de fecha... esas fechas deben tener un inicio y un final ...

entonces tienes dos opciones dar esas fechas manuales mediante dos input en un formulario o obtener las fechas guardaras en una tercera tabla.

para las dos opciones necesitas usar `between` he `inner join`

**asumiendo que:**
la tabla `servicio_fecha` es donde se guarda la fecha en que se ejecuto el servicio y el id del servicio dado al cliente.
y que la tabla `servicios` simplemente guardas los tipos de servicios ofrecidos (Master de Servicios)

**opción 1 - mediante un input:**

necesitas usar `between` he `inner join` esto busca y trae todo lo que este en medio de los rangos de fecha algo como esto te solucionaría el problema.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    servicios
INNER JOIN servicios_fecha ON servicios_fecha.facha BETWEEN '2016-02-19' AND '2016-03-20';
```

sustituyendo las fechas mediante el input 1 y 2 del formulario

**opción 2 - mediante una tercera tabla:**

en este caso requieres una tercera tabla (no uses la de servicios) para facturar por rango de fecha en donde guardas el rango de fecha que deseas facturar...

```
SELECT *
FROM servicios
INNER JOIN servicio_factura AS sf
    ON sf.id_servicio_factura = servicios.id_servico
INNER JOIN servicio_fecha AS sd
    ON sd.facha BETWEEN sf.servicio_fecha_id_1 AND sf.servicio_fecha_id_2
WHERE servicios.id_servicio = sf.servicio_id;
```

Esta claramente documentado en esta respuesta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4474/46896

https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/hosting/cuestiones-tecnicas/inner-join/

Comment: Tal vez no fui especifico, no quiero comparar entre un rango de fechas, sino, quiero crear una tabla x donde pueda facturar por un rango de fechas

Comment: la tabla que deseas la debes crear tal cual lo indicas con la fecha A y B y la debes remplazar donde esta el between ... al final la tabla para saber que vas a facturar terminara siendo la de servicios para que sea mas facil para la base de datos ...

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, entonces debo crear una tabla donde se guarde solo fechas y en servicios crear un campo factura? Podrias ponerlo, soy nuevo en estos temas

Comment: dejame actualizar la respuesta

Comment: @gixilir521 verifica la respuesta. creo que son las opciones que tienes... asumiendo que vas a usar una tercera tabla, y no reutilizar la tabla de servicios como indicas.

Comment: Entre los dos casos, el primero de los inputs, deberia crear una tabla donde contengan la fecha1,fecha2,nro_factura? Y en el segundo caso, como guardia los datos?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez la opcion 1 te devolveria todos registros de esas fechas sin especificar que servicio facturar. La opcion 2 estas diciendo `servicios.id_servico = sf.id_servicio_factura` cosa que esta mal porque deberia ser `servicios.id_servicio = sf.servicio_id`

Comment: es que el no ha dicho que solo quiera facturar un servicio ..... de la tabla principal ... en ese caso se facturarian todos los servicios dentro del rango de fecha. esa es la opcion 1...

Comment: y la opción 2 si tienes razón ya la corregí.